# Laravel extend package class

Tags: php, laravel-4

I added a cart package to my Laravel install, but I need to add a method to the class.  If I modify the class directly, will my changes be overwritten when I update to a newer version?  If so, what's the best method for modifying a package without breaking future updates?

Thanks for the help!
-JB

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if there is any general process to extend Laravel 5.0 package from vendor directory and I am sure this may be different for different packages. But saying that,  I faced the same issue when I wanted to extend this [cart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) . But I managed it somehow and steps I followed are below. I hope it may give some hint.

1. Install the package

   ```
   composer require "gloudemans/shoppingcart":"~1.3"
   ```
2. Create directory `app/Services/Cart` and a new class `MyCart` under it

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Services\Cart;

   use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart;

   class MyCart extends Cart
   {

   }
   ```
3. create `CartServiceProvider` under `app/Providers` directory,

   ```
   <?php namespace App\Providers;

    use App\Services\Cart\MyCart;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   class CartServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

   /**
    * Bootstrap the application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function boot()
   {
       //
   }

   /**
    * Register the application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function register()
   {
       $this->app['mycart'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
       {
           $session = $app['session'];
           $events = $app['events'];
           return new MyCart($session, $events);
       });
   }
   ```

   }
4. Create `MyCartFacade` under `app/Services/Cart` directory,

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Services\Cart;

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

   class MyCartFacade extends Facade {
       protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'mycart'; }
   }
   ```
5. in `config/app.php` add following in `providers` array

   ```
   'App\Providers\CartServiceProvider'
   ```

   and following in `aliases` array

   ```
   'MyCart'      => 'App\Services\Cart\MyCartFacade'
   ```

   That's it. Now in my controller I placed following code. `add` and `content` are method in base `Cart` class.

   ```
   \MyCart::add('293ad', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99, array('size' => 'large'));
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r(\MyCart::content());
   exit();
   ```

   and following is the output,

   ```
   Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartCollection Object
   (
       [items:protected] => Array
           (
               [0f6524cc3c576d484150599b3682251c] => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartRowCollection Object
                   (
                       [associatedModel:protected] => 
                       [associatedModelNamespace:protected] => 
                       [items:protected] => Array
                           (
                               [rowid] => 0f6524cc3c576d484150599b3682251c
                               [id] => 293ad
                               [name] => Product 1
                               [qty] => 1
                               [price] => 9.99
                               [options] => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartRowOptionsCollection Object
                                   (
                                        [items:protected] => Array
                                           (
                                               [size] => large
                                           )

                                   )

                               [subtotal] => 9.99
                           )

                   )

           )

   )
   ```

Now if you want to add or override functionality simply put that function in `MyCart` class.

The good thing is, you can update the base package.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks and if i want to ovveride method shoud i use parent:: ?