# Extending Cashier package in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-cashier

I am in desperate need of extending the `\Laravel\Cashier\Subscription` with 2 new functions that add new relationships to the `Subscription` model.

I took a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076332/laravel-extend-package-class/31421904#31421904) and I was wondering if there is easier way to add 4 rows of code without adding new service provider ?

Comment: You could fork it and add your code that way

Comment: Not really an option, I have done that as for development, but .. not really a production solution.

Comment: Personally, I think the solution proposed in that answer is your best option. Unless the package explicitly provides it's own extension mechanism (Like many Laravel packages do, often through the use of an `::extend(..);` method).